# How do you use jQuery .data() to store html?

Tags: jquery

when I look up the syntax for .data(), it gives examples like this:

```
$('body').data('foo', 52);
```

I am doing AJAX loads and I was wondering if it is possible to store the incoming html using .data() so once the content is loaded, I would not need to do another AJAX load if the same link is clicked again - I would check to see if the .data key is empty.

Would something like this work?:

To load the contents of a #ajaxdiv into storage:

```
$('body').data('storage', div#ajaxdiv.html());
```

To test if the data has already been loaded:

```
if $('body').data('storage') != '' {

div#ajaxdiv.html($('body').data('storage'));

}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: After looking at this again, I'm not really sure why you're storing the data in the `body` element. Keep in mind that the `data()` method is not a replacement for all variables-- just data that you want associated with a given element.  See my example below for more on this.

It should work fine. The `data()` method is like storing data into a variable, but that data is now conveniently associated with the element itself.

You should be careful to namespace the key you use for your data, though. In your code, you're using `'storage'`, but that's awfully generic and seems very susceptible to collisions with other code.  I would suggest using a prefix, like: `'blah.storage'`.

Also, SLaks was correct-- your selector will need to be passed through jQuery.

```
// SLaks' correction and my namespace suggestion
$('body').data('blah.storage', $('#ajaxdiv').html());

// Alternative method, where #ajaxLink is the link you click to trigger
// the data retrieval
$('#ajaxLink').bind('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Notice that we're using $(this).data(), so that our cache is associated
    // with the link element itself.

    if ($(this).data('blah.cachedAjaxHtml')) {
        // The data was found in the cache. Use it to populate the div.
        $('#ajaxDiv').html($(this).data('blah.cachedAjaxHtml'));
    } else {
        // Load the data via AJAX and store it in the cache
        var ajaxResult = whateverYouDoToLoadIt();

        $(this).data('blah.cachedAjaxHtml', ajaxResult);
        $('#ajaxDiv').html(ajaxResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses everyone - awgy's code is EXACTLY what I was looking for to get me on the right path - I've got everything working beautifully!! BTW, I was just using body as an example - I went ahead and associated the cache with the link element as awgy suggested.

Thanks again - much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `$('div#ajaxdiv').html`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').data('storage', div#ajaxdiv.html());
```

...should be...

```
$('body').data('storage', $('#ajaxdiv').html());
```

...and...

```
div#ajaxdiv.html($('body').data('storage'));
```

...should be...

```
$('#ajaxdiv').html($('body').data('storage'));
```